# Add custom text when hovering over each row of datatable

Tags: r, dt

I have the datatable below in which when I hover in each row I should get:

when hovering on 1st row: “Total cases in the world”

when hovering on 2nd row: “Total deaths in the world”

when hovering on 3rd row: “Total cases in the selected countries”

when hovering on 4th row: “Total deaths in the selected countries”

```
V1<-c(2,3,4,5)
fd<-data.frame(V1)

rownames(fd)[1:4]<-c("Total cases",  "Total deaths", "Cases",        "Deaths")

library(DT)
datatable(fd,colnames = rep("", ncol(fd)),
          options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 't',
                         rowCallback = JS(
                           "function(row, data) {",
                           "var full_text = 'This rows values are :' + data[0] ",
                           "$('td', row).attr('title', full_text);",
                           "}")
                         
                         
          ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add some simple logic in the `rowCallback` function to get the desired text when hovering over the rows.

```
V1<-c(2,3,4,5)
fd<-data.frame(V1)

rownames(fd)[1:4]<-c("Total cases",  "Total deaths", "Cases", "Deaths")

library(DT)
datatable(fd,colnames = rep("", ncol(fd)),
          options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 't',
                         rowCallback = JS(
                           "function(row, data) {",
                           "
                            if (data[0].startsWith('Total')) {
                              var full_text = data[0] +' in the world.';
                            } else {
                              var full_text = 'Total ' + data[0].toLowerCase() +' in selected countries.';
                            }
                            console.log(data);
                            ",
                           "$('td', row).attr('title', full_text);",
                           "}")
                         
                         
          ))
```